# Finding Speeds of two bodies after elastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, collision, elasticity

This is a past paper question from FM Mechanics. It's been an hour and I cannot figure out a solution to this question:

Particles of masses **m1** and **m2** lie at rest on a smooth horizontal plane. Each particle is given a horizontal impulse of magnitude ***I*** towards the other particle so that the particles collide directly. Given that the collision is perfectly elastic, find the speeds of the particles after the collision.

Spoilers ahead!
- The velocity (answer) of each particle is given in terms of the respective mass of the particle.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)

Comment: a hint: $v_1 = I/m_1$, $v_2 = I/m_2$. So you know initial velocities and and initial masses. My suggestion would be to take a frame where one is at rest and apply conservation of energy and momentum. Then it is just a matter of finding the nicest method of solution for variables. Also, homework questions are not suitable for this website

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to solve it for you, but I will give you the following hints. As you know the masses you can calculate the respective velocities $v = \frac{I}{m}$. However there are two velocities afterwards and you only know that momentum is conserved:
$$I_1 + I_2 = I_3 + I_4 .$$
Well of course you also know that kinetic energy is conserved as the collision is inelastic:
$$\sum E_{kin} = const.$$
So know you have two equations and two unknowns. You should be able to derive the velocity equations now.